# Pthreads in C, Second Thread Won't Execute

Tags: c, pthreads

I have this code that reads in two int numbers from a file. And stores it in a buffer[] to be taken in a second function to be used. I'm not sure if my stopping conditions in the first function are correct. It looks fine but when running the code it stops at the second function.

```
static int count = 0;
int buffer[5];
int requestNum = 1;
FILE* f;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /*THREAD IDs*/
    pthread_t liftR, lift1;

    /*OPEN FILE*/
    f = fopen("sim_input.txt", "r");

    /*CREATE THREAD*/
    pthread_create(&liftR, NULL, request, NULL);
    pthread_create(&lift1, NULL, lift, NULL);

    /*RUNS TILL THREADS FINISHED*/
    pthread_join(liftR, NULL);
    pthread_join(lift1, NULL);
    /*CLEAN UP*/
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
} 
void* request(void* data1)
{
    int req1, req2, eof;

    /*NOT EOF*/
    while(eof != -1)
    {
        /*READ ONE REQUEST*/
        eof = fscanf(f, "%d %d", &req1, &req2);

        /*CHECK IF BUFFER FULLL*/
        if(count < 5)
        {
            /*ADD REQUEST TO BUFFER*/
            buffer[count] = req1;
            buffer[count + 1] = req2;

            count = count + 2;
            printf("COUNT: %d\n", count);
            /*PRINTING*/
            printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("From Buffer -> Item1: %d, Item2: %d\n", req1, req2);
            printf("Request No: %d\n", requestNum);
            printf("-------------------------------------------\n");

            requestNum++;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}  

void* lift(void* data2)
{
    while(count > 0)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("================\n");
        printf("COUNT: %d\n", count);
        printf("REMOVE ITEM FROM BUFFER - DO STUFF WITH IT\n");
        printf("================\n");
        count = count - 2;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

OUTPUT:
Shows count 2, 4, 6. Only 3 request shown, In file it goes up to 10 request

Comment: You are declaring the callbacks incorrectly, they should be `void* func (void*)`, not `void* func()`.

Comment: @Lundin in lift() and request(), I should put void* as parameters?

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything..........

Comment: Your code does not compile, nor do you give the input data, which makes it really hard for others.

Comment: This is probably a race condition, as you have two threads touching shared data without a mutex.

Comment: ...and eof is tested when uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple bugs in your program:

1. Reading uninitialized `eof` variable:

```
    int int req1, req2, eof;  // What is the value of eof? It could be -1 (or anything else).

    /*NOT EOF*/
    while(eof != -1)
```

2. You throw away the data you read:

```
        if(count < 5)
        {
            /*ADD REQUEST TO BUFFER*/
        }
```

If the first thread runs for a while before the second thread starts, then it will store the first two requests into the `buffer`, and *throw away the rest*.

To fix this, you need to wait for the second thread to drain the `buffer` when it is full.

3. You access `count` without any locking, which is a data race and undefined behavior. You must protect reading and writing shared (between threads) globals with a mutex.